Renormalisation in quantum optics
When reading about QED in QFT books, renormalisation seems to be essential to get results eventually. It also seems absolutely necessary even for low energies, since the internal lines lead to divergences. When reading in quantum optics books about QED, somehow renormalisation does not appear. Anybody knows why?

In quantum optics, the calculations usually only involve tree level diagrams, which does not require renormalisation. Such calculations are only relevant when considering nonlinear interactions. In the context of quantum optics such nonlinearities are found in parametric down-conversion, for example. Because the conversion efficiency is very low without bosonic enhancement, higher order diagrams are not considered. Even with bosonic enhancement, one usually uses a semiclassical approach that converts the vertex to a two-point vertex, which does not allow loop diagrams. Moreover, the vertex rule in parametric down-conversion is smoothed by the phase matching condition, which introduces natural cut-off scales for the process, thus avoiding divergences.
That is not to say that you cannot end up with divergent quantities in some calculations in quantum optics, but these are easier to handle than in particle physics, because they always cancel when one calculates any measurable quantity.

Thanks. Do you have a reference/example for the last paragraph with divergent quantities where they cancel for measurable quabtities.

As an example, in functional phase space calculations where the phase space is infinite dimensional, the normalization constants of the Wigner functionals of states could be divergent constants. When you trace over such a state one must get 1 for the state to be normalized. Therefore the divergent constants cancel out.
